# Confirm module uninstall

Tags: nodes

I have written a module that creates a node type and I want to put in a warning on uninstall that lets the user know that the nodes created under that node type will be deleted if they continue to uninstall the module.

Now someone suggested that I use the confirm_form function. But I don't see how this would work or even apply in this case since it has to integrate with the hook_uninstall function for the module.

Any thoughts on this? Thanks!

EDIT: This module is written in Drupal 6 with a Drupal 7 version coming once this one has been approved by the Drupal community (my first community posted module, so I am not yet sure how to create the separate version branches yet).

Comment: After doing more research I feel that I was led astray on this. Drupal automatically asks if you want to uninstall something after you select an item to be uninstalled. Uninstalling is not the same as disabling. The above hook from iStriker does not seem to exist anywhere in the Drupal API. So either it is not documented at all or it simply does not exist. I have decided to close this question.

Comment: [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) is a well documented hook. If the hook is implemented by the "mymodule" module, for a form that uses "system_modules_uninstall" as form ID, the function implementing the hook is `mymodule_form_system_modules_uninstall_alter()`.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 6 you can alter the system modules uninstall form.

```
function MYMODULE_form_system_modules_uninstall_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if (isset($form['modules']['MYMODULE'])) {
    //alter form how you would like
  }
}
```

The only change for Drupal 7 is there is an additional function argument

```
6       hook_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state)
7 – 8   hook_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
```

NOTE: This form gets call on the /admin/module/uninstall & /admin/module/uninstall/confirm.   If you just want it on one then add an additional case to the if statment, checking the path.

Comment: @iStryker: When a question is version agnostic, add no version tag instead of both. Version tags should only be used when explicitly necessary, we had a long discussion about that on meta (And yeah, the current 7 tag is a mess)

Comment: @iStryker: I am not seeing this unintall form so far nor a corresponding hook. I will keep looking through the API and the base code to see if I can find it. Are you sure this works in D6?

Comment: yes I've tested it in 6 & 7, and they both call system_modules_uninstall

Comment: can also do function example_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 if($form_id == 'system_modules_uninstall') {
     if (isset($form['modules']['overlay'])) {
  //do something
   }
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

A module that is uninstalled through the user interface is first disabled, and then uninstalled. As consequence of this, the code that shows the user a warning before the module is uninstalled cannot be contained in the module that implements the content type. It should be contained in a module that is required from the module implementing the content type; in this way, the module that would warn the user about the content type being deleted could not be uninstalled before the module implementing the content type. (I will report after why I think that implementing this code is not worth the time spent.)

Supposing that base_module.module is the module showing the warning, and content_type.module is the module implementing the content type, you could write the following code. (The code is for Drupal 7, but similar code could be easily written for Drupal 6.)

```
function base_module_menu_alter(&$items) {
  if (isset($items['admin/modules/uninstall'])) {
    $items['admin/modules/uninstall']['page arguments'] = array('base_module_uninstall');
  }
}

function base_module_uninstall($form, $form_state = NULL) {
  if (!empty($form_state['storage'])) {
    if (isset($form_state['storage']['uninstall']['content_type'])) {
      // Show a warning message on the top of the page.
    }
  }

  return system_modules_uninstall($form, $form_state);
}
```

The code is simple, but it works just in a case: when base_module.module is still enabled when content_type.module is uninstalled; differently, the code adding the warning would not be shown. The problem is that the users could first disable the two modules, one at time, and then proceed with uninstalling them; if this happens, the warning would not be shown.

Considering this, and the fact other modules (including core modules) don't implement such code, I think that implementing it is not worth the time spent.
If such a feature is required, it should be implemented in Drupal. As the Node module is required in the default profile (otherwise, it would not be possible to create content types, and nodes), the warning would always be shown.